# require('child_process'); give error Electron

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, electron

I've been smashing my head on this for the last couple days.

I keep getting this error but don't know how to fix it. All the fixes I've found online don't work.

And yes it is compiling from TS to JS.

Here is the error,

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at OpenCmd (cmd.js:9:22) at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (cmd.js:5:9)`

Here is the HTML file the JavaScript file and the Typescript file,

TS (Typescript)

```
(() => {
    document.querySelector('#CompileButton') ?. addEventListener('click', () => {
        OpenCmd();
    })
})()

function OpenCmd(): void {
    const {exec} = require('child_process');

    let commandOne = "start cmd.exe";
    let commandTwo = "cd 'E:/Repos/DS-Creator/DSTest/AutorunnerTests/A_Autorunner'";
    let commandThree = "make";

    exec(`${commandOne} && ${commandTwo} && ${commandThree}`, (error : any, stdout : any, stderr : any) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`error: ${
                error.message
            }`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`Output: ${stdout}`);
    });
}
```

JS (JavaScript)

```
"use strict";
(() => {
    var _a;
    (_a = document.querySelector('#CompileButton')) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.addEventListener('click', () => {
        OpenCmd();
    });
})();
function OpenCmd() {
    const { exec } = require('child_process');
    let commandOne = "start cmd.exe";
    let commandTwo = "cd 'E:/Repos/DS-Creator/DSTest/AutorunnerTests/A_Autorunner'";
    let commandThree = "make";
    exec(`${commandOne} && ${commandTwo} && ${commandThree}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`Output: ${stdout}`);
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DSC : Project Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Opened : File Name</h1>
    <h2>File directory</h2>

    <button id="CompileButton" >Compile</button>

    <script src="../src/client/compiler/cmd.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

- Kenyon Bowers

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it. Sorry if someone finds this.

Comment: You should add you answer here just in case others have the same problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).